# Getting Workbook.Open To Schedule My Macro Everyday (Not just one time through)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that I'm trying to get to run every 30min between 6pm and 230pm the following day.

I've tried to use Workbook.Open and the Application.OnTime to accomplish this but I'm realizing it looks like it'll only schedule everything 1x. The 2nd day, nothing ran. I have this code in the ThisWorkbook VBA page.

How can I modify this so it runs continuously on those hour without having to close and reopen the sheet

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:30:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("19:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("19:30:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("20:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("20:30:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("21:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("21:30:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("22:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("23:30:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("00:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("00:30:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("01:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("01:30:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("02:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("02:30:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("03:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("03:30:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("04:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("04:30:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("05:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("05:30:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("06:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("06:30:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("07:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("07:30:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("08:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("08:30:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("09:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("09:30:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:30:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("11:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("11:30:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("12:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("12:30:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:30:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:00:00"), "PopulateData"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:30:00"), "PopulateData"

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you done any research?   You would redo the `application.ontime` at the end of `PopulateData`  So when first set, set a variable to the time, then in `PopulateData` set to this variable+60mins.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924247/excel-application-ontime-to-run-on-the-hour-every-hour-regardless-of-when-the-ti   http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Application.OnTime_en.html

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Sorry - Im not fluent in VBA so this is a little over my head. I will mention that I need it to run at those times. If it's just time+30 wouldn't it run all day outside of my time parameter (8pm-230pm only)?

Comment: Does the Workbook remain open during this time, or does it close itself after running?

Comment: @CLR It stays open all the time

Comment: Also - one other question. If my worksheet crashes and I have to reopen it - will it run 2x at every time indicated in the workbook.open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this a lot simpler using the following:
Place the following in your `ThisWorkbook`

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim t As Long
    t = 24 / (30 / 60)
    Application.OnTime TimeValue(Format(WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(Now * t, 1) / t, "HH:mm:ss")), "UpdateCaller"
End Sub
```

which calls

```
Public Sub UpdateCaller()
    Dim tme As Date
    Dim t As Long

    If TimeValue(Format(Now, "HH:mm:ss")) <= TimeValue("14:30:00") Or TimeValue(Format(Now, "HH:mm:ss")) >= TimeValue("18:00:00") Then
        Call PopulateData
    End If

    t = 24 / (30 / 60)
    tme = TimeValue(Format(WorksheetFunction.Ceiling((Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")) * t, 1) / t, "HH:mm:ss"))
    Debug.Print "Procedure ""UpdateCaller"" will next run at: ", tme

    Application.OnTime tme, "UpdateCaller"
End Sub
```

You will need to keep the workbook open. If the workbook is closed, you could use Windows Task Scheduler to open it every 30 minutes instead.

Comment: But this will have it run every 30 min of the day wont it? I only need it to run at those specific times. (every 30 min from 6pm in the evening until 230pm the following day)

Comment: also, if i open the workbook at 10:15am - wont this then run at 10:45, 11:15 etc? I'd need it to at 1030, 1100, 1130 etc regardless of when the sheet was opened

Comment: Do i have the understanding right? When I first open the workbook, it will round the time to the nearest 30 min? and schedule the sheet to run UpdateCaller. what does that now+ Time(value("00:00:05") line doing?

Comment: Correct. I'm adding 5 seconds on for the second caller to ensure that it rounds the time up to the next half hour otherwise if your code is fast enough to run in the same second it will stay on the previous half hour and wouldn't get called again

Comment: ahh ok. So updatecaller will just be scheduled to run 1x on the next 30 min period when I first open the worksheet.  The tme line will add 5 seconds and return the next 30 min period. How do you get it to run though b/c If im reading it correctly, Say it's 935. The sheet will open, decide the next time is 1000. It'll run Update caller. At 10am - wont it add 5 seconds to the current time, round up to 1030 and then run PopulateData since it's within the time constraints then it'll run again. Does that mean that this macro is just constantly looping every every second to keep checking the time?

Comment: sorry - im just trying to understand so I can troubleshoot down the line. Im sure this is annoying

Comment: also - does the tme variable used int he worksheet_open have to be defined?

Comment: Yup - you're correct, sorry am trying to write this in between meetings and in my haste missed a bit. See - questions are good. Have update the `UpdateCaller` proc. When the workbook opens it up it will get the next half hour period and initiate the call to the `UpdateCaller` proc which will run the `PopulateData` proc if within the given time slot. It will then calculate the next half hour to run the program on and set it to call itself every half hour then on.

Comment: ah ok - thank you so much for helping with this between meetings. It sould solve such a big problem for me. The only other issue I'm having is when I step through the code right now, the first If statement in the UpdateCaller prog is returning false for some reason even though the current time is 10:09am which should fall between those time values?

Comment: Apologies - `And` should've been `Or`

Comment: Thank you X10000 - I think that should do it and it makes sense to me now.

Comment: np - Got there in the end